# Need to get current network server names

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-2008

I am using enumerator for getting list of server names, But I am getting only one.

```
         DataTable table = System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();
        foreach (DataRow server in table.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(server[table.Columns["ServerName"]].ToString());
            Console.Read();
        }
```

But i am getting only one server name, what wrong in this code.
Please help me!

Comment: Does it work if you take out the `Console.Read`?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
DataTable table = System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();
foreach (DataRow server in table.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(server["ServerName"].ToString());
    Console.Read();
}
```